# App Engine unencoded String as key -- is there an upper bound on the string length?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

Suppose we have a JDO entity that uses an unencoded string as the `PrimaryKey`.   Is there some practical limit on the size that this unencoded string could be? Specifically, I'm wondering if I could use a `String` that is extremely large, e.g. 500+ KB in size.

I understand the app engine quotas on in-memory object size (1MB) and datastore entity size (32MB), I'm wondering about the key field itself. Before you start ripping me for bad design and telling me to use entity relationships, this is a theoretical question, and is something that I don't intend to abuse.

Comment: If you're looking to make a long string the unique identifier of an entity, you may want to consider hashing it and using the hash as the key instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python a key name is limited to 500 characters.  The limit should be pretty easy to test in Java as well.

Having a super long key name is not a good idea though.  It would cause your indexes to consume a lot more space and probably increase write overhead.

See [How Entities and Indexes are Stored](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/storage_breakdown.html#anc-indextables) for more details.

Comment: I'm confused, I don't see where it lists the unencoded key limit in that article.

Comment: @Travis It doesn't list a hard limit; I'm not aware of a hard limit being listed anywhere.  I was suggesting to *test* this and providing you with some thoughts on why a long key name is not a good idea, plus the docs for you to read about how indexes / entity storage works.  In one of the 08 or 09 IO talks a presenter mentions there being an actual limit (possibly http://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore)